# Console App not working in Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application

I have a console app which calls a command line program:

```
var commandArgs = String.Format(@"/C """"{0}""  /user:""{1}"" /password:""{2}"" /report:""{3}"" /paramfile:params.xml /Quiet """" ", PathToExe, Username, Password, name);
```

The app runs perfectly when I run it from the command prompt.

However, if I run the console app from Task Scheduler, it fails everytime when trying to call the command line.

If I put the same code into a Windows Service, it also fails in the same way.

Is there a permissions issue when running in Task Scheduler. Can anyone shed any light on why this is happening.

I have tried using absolute paths and relative paths. I have tried to change the quotation marks around the command argument: see http://www.mobzystems.com/code/bugingetcommandlineargs/
but nothing works in the Task Scheduler, but works like clockwork without fail when run directly from the command line.

Comment: did you ever fix this?

Comment: @Fred - not yet. It has been on the back burner.

Comment: I am having the same problem albeit with a more complex console app.  I will post back here if I solve it.

Comment: Not sure this will be a fix for your problem but..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125750/sheduled-task-fails-unspecified-error